# how to refer an external jar file in build.xml file

Tags: java, ant

I created a swing application with an external jar file that is date picker and run the application it is working fine. So, I wrote a build.xml file to create a jar for my application and I added external jars to the `build.xml` file also even though it is failing to create an executable jar file

Here is my `build.xml` file to add an external jar files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<project basedir=".">
<property name="build.dir" location="${basedir}/build"/>  
<property name="lib.dir" location="${basedir}/lib"></property>  
<path id="classpath">  
<fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />  
</path>  

<target name="clean">  

<delete dir="build"/>  
</target>  

<target name="compile">  

<mkdir dir="${build.dir}/classes"/>  
<javac srcdir="src" destdir="${build.dir}/classes" classpathref=  
"classpath" includeantruntime="false"/>  
</target>  

<target name="jar">  
<mkdir dir="${build.dir}/jar"/>  
<jar destfile="${build.dir}/jar/date.jar   
"basedir="${build.dir}/classes">  
<manifest>  
<attribute name="Class-Path" value="${lib.dir}/*.jar" />  
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.pavan.LoginPage"/>  
</manifest>  
</jar>  
</target>  

<target name="run">  
<java jar="${build.dir}/jar/date.jar" fork="true"/>  
</target>  
</project>
```

I am getting the below exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pavan/LoginPage  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pavan.LoginPage  
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)    
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)    
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
Could not find the main class: com.pavan.LoginPage. Program willexit.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i tried with your suggestions but i got this exception  java.io.IOException: invalid header field name: ${classpath}
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
   Exception in thread "main"  --- MadProgrammer

Comment: Once I correct some mistakes in the ant script (putting spaces between attributes `srcdir="src"destdir="${build.dir}/classes"classpathref="classpath"`) and "fake" some of the functionality, it works find for me.  The problem seems to be with the execution of the jar.  Try adding dependencies to the `run` target to depend on `jar`, and have `jar` depend on `compile` to make sure that the code is compiled and jar'ed first

Comment: hi MadProgrammer ,  you suggested regarding the spaces but my ant script is having the spaces but when i put my code into stack overflow this syntax was missing spaces ----->srcdir="src"destdir="${build.dir}/classes"classpathref="classpath" but my code is having spaces.

Comment: Then I suggest making sure that your run target depends on your jar target which depends on your compile target